# Is it possible to replace content in a file without deleting the file?

Tags: rust

I am wondering is it possible to replace contents without?
I have tried this with `file.write()`, however, it has just been added to the content of the file, not replacing it. Does it possible to replace the contents in a file without deleting the file itself?

`the_json_file.write_all(inside_da_file.as_bytes()).expect("Failed to write");`I wanted to clear out the file before I write into it.

Comment: Hi @TaceCat, please give us an example (code) of what you want to do

Comment: Does [How to replace a word in a file in a .txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215396/how-to-replace-a-word-in-a-file-in-a-txt) help?

Comment: Hi @gedflod, I have edited it and what I wanted to do is listed on top.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65782872/how-to-delete-the-contents-of-a-file-before-writing-to-it-in-rust

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented under [`OpenOptions::truncate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.truncate):

> Sets the option for truncating a previous file.
>
> If a file is successfully opened with this option set it will truncate
> the file to 0 length if it already exists.
>
> The file must be opened with write access for truncate to work.
>
> #### Examples
>
> ```rust
> use std::fs::OpenOptions;
>
> let file = OpenOptions::new().write(true).truncate(true).open("foo.txt");
> ```

Alternatively, to truncate the file after it has been opened, there's [`File::set_len`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.set_len) followed by [`Seek::rewind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html#method.rewind):

```rust
use std::io::{Seek, Write};

the_json_file.set_len(0).unwrap();
the_json_file.rewind().unwrap();
the_json_file.write_all(inside_da_file.as_bytes()).expect("Failed to write");
```